# Regarding CRO output waveform for given input

Tags: electromagnetism

If we provide signal y=Acoswt to the y-plate of CRO and no signal to the x-plate then what will be the output waveform ?

Comment: A vertical line.

Comment: A vertical line.  What do you think you would get?

Answer (score 0):

*Think* about it.  You are plotting a sine on the vertical axis with a constant on the horizontal axis.  The instantaneous point will therefore bounce back and forth vertically, staying at the same horizontal position.

The vertical range will be the sine range.  That's ±A from your equation.

In other words, you get a vertical line.